# Prevent people from targeting specific branches on Github

Tags: github

I would like to know if there's a way of protecting specific branches from random people that wants to contribute to a project.

For example:

I've master, develop and beta branches in my project and sometimes people create pull request targeting master or even beta. What I would like is that, when they create their pull request only the develop branch can be the selected (aka "Base" on github)

[image: like this]

Is this possible ?

Comment: Reject the bad pull request. Or just retarget it.

Comment: Note that the method you'd use on GitHub would require some kind of tweaks/changes for any other Git hosting site, so I've snipped the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Similarely to the [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) (workflow set on GitHub server side) "[`hmarr/auto-approve-action`](https://github.com/hmarr/auto-approve-action)", you can write then set-up an "auti-reject action".

```yaml
name: Auto approve
on: pull_request_target

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: <you>/auto-reject-action@v1
      with:
        github-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

That action would automatically *reject* a PR done with, as a target, a branch you would not approve of.

```js
await client.pulls.createReview({
      owner: context.repo.owner,
      repo: context.repo.repo,
      pull_number: prNumber,
      event: "REJECT",
    });
    core.info(`pull request #${prNumber} done on the wrong branch`);
```